# How to define a "GeoPoint" property in Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to geo-tag an Open Graph story by creating an Open Graph object that inherits from the predefined "place" object. However, I can't figure out how to define the GeoPoint property "place:location" in iOS! There is an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19386730/824515 which I have tried without success.

Now, I'm trying to break down the problem by setting up a "place" object directly, but it doesn't help. I get this error message:

```
error =         {
        code = 100;
        message = "(#100) Object Missing a Required Value: Object at URL '' of type 'place' is invalid because a required property 'place:location' of type 'geo_point' was not provided.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
```

This is my test code:

A:

```
FBRequestConnection *connection = [[[FBRequestConnection alloc] init] autorelease];
id<FBOpenGraphObject> object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
object[@"type"] = @"place";
object[@"title"] = @"Test Title";

object[@"location"] = @{@"latitude": @"48.85831", @"longitude": @"2.29465"};

NSLog(@"object = %@", [object description]);
FBRequest *objectRequest = [FBRequest requestForPostOpenGraphObject: object];
[connection addRequest: objectRequest
     completionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         DLine();
         if (error)
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         else
             NSLog(@"Result: %@", [result description]);
     }];
[connection start];
```

I have tried to replace the line `object[@"location"] = …` with everything I can think of, such as:

B:

```
object[@"place:location"] = @{@"latitude": @"48.85831", @"longitude": @"2.29465"};
```

C:

```
object[@"place"] = @{@"location":
                         @{@"latitude": @"48.85831", @"longitude": @"2.29465"}
                     };
```

D:

```
object[@"location:latitude"] = @"48.85831";
object[@"location:longitude"] = @"2.29465";
```

E:

```
object[@"place:location:latitude"] = @"48.85831";
object[@"place:location:longitude"] = @"2.29465";
```

The error message was identical for all the versions A - E.

Comment: have you tried with `[object setObject:@{@"latitude":@"48.85831", 
                             @"longitude": @"2.29465"}
                 forKey:@"location"];` ?

Comment: @Virussmca: Ha, you edited while I was typing ;-) Anyway, I have tried it. It is totally equivalent to my version "A".

Comment: Hi there from 2015! I have exactly the same issue now, did you figured it out back then? Please save my day.

Comment: Sorry vlad24, I could not solve this back then, so I dropped it and have not checked for any updates since then.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they need to be nested dictionaries, so you need to create a "place" graph object, and then set that as the place on your open graph object. Something like:

```
id<FBGraphObject> place = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
id<FBGraphObject> location = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
location[@"latitude"] = @"48.85831";
location[@"longitude"] = @"2.29465";
place[@"location"] = location;
place[@"name"] = @"foobar";

object[@"place"] = place;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it did not work. The resulting dictionary became almost identical to version "C" in the question (verified with the NSLog statement), with the only difference that you has assigned a "name" to the "place" dictionary.

Comment: Instead of creating a "place" object, why not just add a GeoPoint property to your custom open graph object?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *store = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
store.provisionedForPost = YES;
store[@"og"] = @{ @"title":@"Test Title", @"type":@"place" };
store[@"place"] = @{ @"location" : @{ @"longitude": @"-58.381667", @"latitude":@"-34.603333"} };

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/place"
                                 graphObject:@{@"object":store}
                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                               id result,
                                               NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
  }
  else {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.description]);
  } 
}];
```

Comment: hey man your answer seems interesting.. but can you please provide some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
object[@"data"][@"location"] = @{@"latitude": @"48.85831", @"longitude": @"2.29465"};
```

Facebook doc doesn't mention it clearly that we should put the additional property under the key `data`.